# Problem With Filling

Tags: plotting, filling, opacity

I am plotting the graph of the logistic equation in a manipulate. My borders range from {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}. I would like to fill the background of the plot with a light grey color, almost completely transparent, over a range from {x, 0, 20}, {Y, 0, 100}. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to fill the background of the plot and don't need to fill under the curve, I would use `Prolog` and `Rectangle`.

```
Plot[
  x,
  {x, 0, 100},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}},
  Prolog -> {
    GrayLevel[0.95],
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {20, 100}]
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like what I'm looking for. Where do I locate the code in a manipulate?

Comment: Without knowing how you're plotting your equation, it's difficult to say. If you're using `Plot`, `ListPlot`, `ParametricPlot`, or some other version, you can do it the way I show. If you're using a `Graphics` environment, then you can simply include the `GrayLevel` and `Rectangle` commands in the list of graphics to create. If you include either a minimal working example, or at least more details, it'll be easier for you to get help.

Comment: I was able to get your code working in a Plot. Unfortunately, when I tried to combine the Plot with other data sets using the function 'Show' your shaded area disappeared.

Comment: If you're using `Show`, any options should either go into the first thing that you're showing, or else go as options to `Show` itself. `Show` only looks at the first thing and takes its options, unless its given options directly. So `Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 100}, Prolog->{stuff}], Plot[otherfunction...]]` should work, or you can do `Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 100}], Plot[...], Prolog->{GrayLevel[0.99], Rectangle[...]}]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything's working, but I have one more request. How do I change the color of the background rectangle to say, light blue?

Comment: @HenryB Instead of `GrayLevel[0.05]` you could do `LightBlue`. If you want more control, you can generate your own colour using `RGBColor[r, g, b]` where r, g, and b would be numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am now completely fluent in Prolog->.